# Recursive integral definition for the dynamics of a DC motor

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, physics

I have been trying to build a simulator of motor dynamics, but am running into the wall of a seemingly recursive integral definition. Currently I am trying to derive a formula for the rpm of a motor at time t.

Here is my reasoning:

The torque output of a dc motor at time t is this:
$$torque(t) = T + D*rpm(t)$$
Where T is the stall torque of the motor and D is the derivative of torque with respect to rpm. (because the torque of a DC motor decreases as rpm increases) And rpm(t) is the rpm of the motor at time t.

Now rpm(t) can be expressed as an integral of $torque(t)$
$$rpm(t) = \frac 1m \int^t_0 torque(i) di$$
where m is the mass of the load attached to the motor and $rpm(0) = 0$

Substituting in my formula for torque gains this:

$$rpm(t) = \frac 1m \int^t_0 T + D*rpm(i) di$$
Which reduces to this:
$$rpm(t) = \frac{Tt}m+D\int^t_0 rpm(i)di$$
Here is where I am stuck. How can I simplify $\int_0^trpm(i)di$? Is this formula even possible to solve? Am I missing something?

Forgive me if this question has been answered already. I have searched numerous times with keywords related to "recursive integrals" and haven't found anything that seems to be relevant. Is there a better term for what I am encountering here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just differentiate both sides to get ($rpm = r$)

$$r'(t) = \frac{T}{m} + D r(t)$$
$$r(0)=0$$

Then we may easily solve this using any of several methods.  The result is

$$r(t) = \frac{T}{m D} \left (e^{D t}-1 \right )$$

Then

$$\int_0^t dt' \, r(t') = \frac{T}{m D} \left (\frac{e^{D t}-1}{D} - t \right ) $$

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity (I am most of the way through calc I, haven't touched calc 2 or 3) How did you get from r'(t)=.. to r(t)=.. ?

Comment: As I said, there are many ways to solve such first-order equations.  For one, you can consider $$\frac{d}{dt}(r e^{-D t})$$.